# Nagios install issue: Failed to enable unit: Unit file nagios.service does not exist

Tags: nagios

I am trying to install Nagios on Alma 8. I am following the instructions on this website: https://www.tecmint.com/install-nagios-in-rocky-linux-and-almalinux/.

In "Step 3 Install Nagios Core on Linux", I run the command `sudo make install-daemoninit` but I get the error message `Failed to enable unit: Unit file nagios.service does not exist.`.

What can I do to address this issue?

Comment: Check if you have nagios script in ` /lib/systemd/system`: `ls -l  /lib/systemd/system/*nagios*`

Comment: After disable selinux, the command runs successfully. I have follow the rest of the instructions in the tutorial but I am now having issues with starting nagios.  I get this in the log ```Caught SIGSEGV, shutting down```.

Comment: Please create new question as this is different problem.